# python: creating numpy nonzero index, value pair

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can get the index of non-zero numpy arrays as follows:

```
a = np.array([0., 1., 0., 2.])
i = np.nonzero(a)
```

This returns `(array([1, 3]),)`. I can get the corresponding values as:

```
v = a[i]
```

Now what I would like to do is create a list with each of the `(index, value)` tuples. I guess one way to do so is to write a `for` loop as follows;

```
l = list()
for x in range(0, len(v)):
    l.append((i[0][x], v[x]))
```

However, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this without writing the loop.

Comment: What is `index` in `index[0][x]`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a type from me. I was doing something in ipython and messed up the variable names during copying. Thanks for pointing it out. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension

```
l = [(x, v[x]) for x in i[0]]
```

or use zip as the other answers suggest

Comment: this is somewhat slower than `zip`, but it's arguably more readable. The order inside the tuple is swapped compared to the example

Comment: I do not think the order is swapped. Here v is iterating over the indexes. I think the confusion is due to the fact that v is something different here than my original example.

Comment: Sorry for that, I changed the variable names to better reflect the original usage in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want tuples, you can get them with:

```
indexes= np.where(a!=0)[0]   #or np.nonzero(a)[0]
values=a[indexes]
zip(values, indexes)         #or list(zip(values, indexes)) in python 3, if you need to access more than once
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if numpy has a library to do that, but you can do this using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function. Example -

```
>>> i = [1,2,3,4]
>>> v = [5,6,7,8]
>>> list(zip(i,v))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

You do not need `list()` for Python 2.x , as zip returns a list of tuples in Python 2.x .

For your case, you can try